# Including External Packages in App for Jailbroken iOS Devices

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

I am building an app that I eventually would like to release on Cydia, however I'm having trouble finding any good documentation on developing apps for jailbroken devices. So firstly, if you have any good links for developing for jailbroken iOS devices that would also be much appreciated!

My current problem is that for my app to work I would require tools from other packages on Cydia like otool and possibly some script interpreter (haven't decided which one yet). Is there a way that I can have these dependencies install alongside my current app in Cydia? I feel like I've seen it before downloading other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

When you build your app, you should make sure to bundle it as a [Debian *package*](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/).  Some repositories will let you just give them a normal .app bundle, which they will then use to build a .deb file.  But, if you want this, I'd recommend [learning to build a .deb bundle yourself](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-debpkg/index.html).  More [instructions from Saurik here](http://www.saurik.com/id/7).

Inside the .deb bundle, you will have a DEBIAN subdirectory, with a file inside named `control`:

```
DEBIAN/control
DEBIAN/postinst
DEBIAN/postrm
DEBIAN/preinst
```

The `control` file is where the Cydia store app description, the app version number (used by the store), and a bunch of other information goes.  An optional field in the `control` file lets you specify that your app has dependencies.  If you list another package as a dependency, that package will automatically get installed when Cydia installs your app.  Something like this:

```
Depends: bigbosshackertools
```

This line is to specify a dependency on the **BigBoss Recommended Tools** package (which is a very large set of packages, so be aware that you're adding a large install set to your own app).

Or, you could try

```
Depends: odcctools
```

to use Saurik's **Darwin CC Tools** package.

I have been building jailbreak apps for a while, so I do it with homemade scripts, but there's now a tool for helping with this called [iOSOpenDev](http://iosopendev.com/download/).  You could use that to build your package, and edit your `control` file, if you aren't already familiar with .deb packages, and don't want to bother (although I'd recommend learning).

Comment: You're welcome.  I updated the answer with the proper package name of a place to get `otool` (the `bigbosshackertools` package).